# How to extract all the Id's value from the Json given below using Regular expression extractor or any other Extractor(Xpath, Beanshell etc)

Tags: regex, json, xpath, jmeter

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "MetaOperationN1",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "GreenOper2",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "GreenOper4",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "GreenOper5",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "GreenOper6",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "GreenOper7",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "GreenOper8",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "GreenOper9",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "GreenOper10",
        "type": "Operation"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "GreenOper11",
        "type": "Operation"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do not use regex to parse Json. Use Json parser.

Comment: Programming language? Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use regex for parsing json docs.. easily done by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

If you want to use regex.. go ahead:

```
"id": (\d+)
```

And extract out ids with `$1`

Answer (score 1):

1. Using Regular Expression Extractor with following configuration:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `ID`
   - Regular Expression: `"id": (\d+),`
   - Template: `$1$`
   - Match No.: `-1`
2. Using [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/))

   - Reference Name: whatever you want, i.e. `ID`
   - JSONPath Expression: `$..id`

In both cases you'll get IDs list as:

```
ID_1=1
ID_10=10
ID_2=2
ID_3=3
ID_4=4
etc.
```

For more information on installing JSON Path Extractor and regarding JSON Path language check out [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON")